# Purchase of Multiple Subscription plan using InAppPurchase

Tags: ios

Currently I am using inAppPurchase Process for the payment in App, after payment user can access each and every digital data of the entire App. Can we create list of  webseries with different price list, and these webseries can be purchased by an user simultaneously(let say user has purchased Webseries1 on paying INR 29 and then after user is able to play the the Webseries1 only not another one from the list of webseries and on the same time  user want to see Another webseries2 costing of INR79. )?

Comment: Yes, you need to create multiple IAP objects in different subscription groups.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, could you please explain more, like how to list the two different subscription groups objects collectiively on a single place.

Comment: Yes its Working .. what i observed is ... for multiple payment we need to Add plans under different Subs Groups.